# Get LinkedIn share count JSONP

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp, linkedin-api

Using the LinkedIn API, I want to get the share count for an URL.

```
https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://www.linkedin.com&format=json
```

But this gives me an error because of Same-Origin Policy.
I want to use JSONP to then get the data, but I am stuck there.

```
$.getJSON("https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://www.linkedin.com&format=jsonp&callback=myCallback", function(data) {
    elem.find(".count").html(data.count);
});
```

I still get the Same-Origin Policy error and no data from data.count.
Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: HI you should try using $.ajax cal and you do not need to specify the callback function in url.

'$.ajax({
                url: url,
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            })'

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
myCallback = function(data) {
  // do stuff with `data`
};
var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?"
          + "url=https://www.linkedin.com&format=jsonp&callback=myCallback";
$.getScript(url);
```

See [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```js
myCallback = function(data) {
  $("body").append("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + "</pre>")
};

$.getScript("https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://www.linkedin.com&format=jsonp&callback=myCallback");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this would not work for linkedin. linkedin API are wierd and not formed properly

Comment: its from experience I have been working with linkedin API like forever. jsonP does not work by defining the function to be called unless you do it using ajax call. you can try it yourself

Comment: @viditbhatia Not able to view stacksnippets results , above ?

Comment: sorry my bad. did not check it but it does not work in the api's i use .i would vote your answer up

Comment: Not sure if things have changed this past year, but this works great for LinkedIn as of today.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your answers, but I solved it already myself.

This worked for me:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://www.linkedin.com&format=jsonp&callback=?", function(data) {
        elem.find(".count").html(data.count);
});
```

Comment: Does not work anymore since LinkedIn updated their API to block callback names with numbers

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.5.1, this is the recommended way of structuring AJAX requests:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: "http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share",
    data: {
        callback: "?",
        format: "jsonp",
        url: "http://www.example.com/"
    }
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.count);
});
```

Comment: jQuery 1.5.1 is [4+ years old](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/01/31/jquery-15-released/). Do you have a link to this recommended structure? Also, you need braces around the parameters to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: This does not work anymore since LinkedIn modified their API to block callbacks with numbers in their name

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago, LinkedIn changed their API and the solutions above are broken :

```
    $.getJSON("http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=https://www.linkedin.com&format=jsonp&callback=?", function(data) {
            elem.find(".count").html(data.count);
    });
```

fails because jQuery will replace the ? into a callback with a random name with numbers in it. And Linkedin now prevents using numbers in callback names.

The solution is to use to call "manually" $.ajax to prevent jQuery automation

```
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share',
        data: {'url':encodeURIComponent(location.href)},
        jsonpCallback: 'this_is_a_random_name',
        success: function(data){
                elem.find(".count").html(data.count);;
        }
    });
```

Comment: The Answer provided by guest271314 still works for me. I appreciate your answer, but are you sure current solutions aren't working anymore?