# Display number of LinkedIn shares, client-only, without authentication

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, linkedin-jsapi

https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=stackoverflow.com&format=json correctly shows the number of shares for `meteor.com` (935 at the moment).

I'm trying to display that number in the client:

```
$.getJSON('https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=stackoverflow.com&format=json&callback=?', { dataType: "jsonp" }, function (data) {
    alert(data.count);
});
```

Because of the `X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff` header being returned, I'm getting the [refuse to execute script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528211/refused-to-execute-script-from-because-its-mime-type-application-json-is) error in Chrome:

> Refused to execute script from 'https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com&format=json&callback=jQuery210014496755180880427_1426891580561&_=1426891580562' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Is there a workaround for this (aside routing the request through a proxy), or is it just impossible, [as is the case with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341122/link-and-execute-external-javascript-file-hosted-on-github), unless [LinkedIn fixes the issue](https://github.com/linkedin/linkedin.github.com/issues/4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a duplicate of this post: [Get LinkedIn share count JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758478/get-linkedin-share-count-jsonp)

Here's the answer recomended over there:

```
myCallback = function(data) {
  alert(data.count);
};

var url = "https://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://stackoverflow.com&format=jsonp&callback=myCallback";
$.getScript(url);
```

Here's a Fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/z9u20ucm/1/

Comment: Ah, `format=jsonp`, not `json`. One character did the trick. Thanks!